# XNA BoundingBox & Origin

Tags: c#, xna

I have seen a few answers on this subject but none have really been much help.

Quite simply, BoundingBox collision. With a origin set at 0,0 the collision occurs fine (at least for how I want it). As I specify the origin of the player to the centre (so it rotates around the middle) the collision seems to be offset and it detects collision at the wrong times

Code(PLayer class):

```
     box = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(location, 0), new Vector3(location.X + texture.width, location.Y + texture.height, 0));
     origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2);

            location.X += speed * (float)Math.Cos(rotation - anglecorrection);
            location.Y += speed * (float)Math.Sin(rotation - anglecorrection);

public BoundingBox getBox()
        {
            return box;
        }
```

Code (Game)

```
BoundingBox box2 = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(location, 0), new Vector3(location.X + 30, location.Y + 30, 0));

 if (player.getBox().Intersects(box2))
            {
                // Do Stuff
            }
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: what does your collision detecting code look like?

Comment: and where is that code?  is it inside your player?  are `box` and `origin` instance variables? if they aren't what happens to them?

Comment: In what manner is your collision offset?  does it appear to be offset by the size of the origin's vector? is it offset by more?

Comment: Just updated the post I hope it's clearer.

Comment: what does the `player.getBox()` method look like?

Comment: do you only encounter your problem when the player is rotated from his starting position?

Comment: no this occurs regardless of the angle the player is facing

Comment: Ah the player.GetBox() simply returns the players bounding box as defined in the code above

Comment: can you post it's code?

Comment: just up dated the post

Answer (score 0):

After much playing around I was able to find a resolution that worked.

I set the scenery item with the BoundingBox called box2 to also have an origin in its centre.

So if both objects have the same point of origin then this seems to fix the problem.